# Loop back to a user entry point after running a script

Tags: python

Sorry quite new to python in the grand scheme of things, basically I want to be able to have an input screen that users have a selection of choices, when a choice has been made a command will run, then give the user the option to go back to the choices to choose another one, or to exit the program completely.

Currently I have

```
print ("1.")
print ("2.")
print ("3.")

errorch=0

while not errorch :
        try :
            choice = int ( input('Please Choose from Options below :') )
            errorch = 1
    except ValueError as e :
            print ("'%s' is not a valid integer." % e.args[0].split(": ")[1])

if choice == 1:
    print ("CODE:")

elif choice == 2:
    print ("OTHER:")

elif choice == 3:
    print ("OTHER:")
else:
    print ("Invalid Choice. Please Try Again:")

k=input('Press close to exit')
```

In each choice I do have code that runs, but to save space I have omitted this

Answer (score 0):

Use a `while` loop.

```
while True: # this loop runs forever
    print("1.")
    ...
    print("4.") # this is for exit

    # get input
    if choice == 1:
    ...

    # if choice is 4, then break out of this loop
    elif choice == 4:
        break # breaks out of the loop
    else:
    ...
```

Comment: That worked well thanks for that, if I wanted to nest another statement that gave the choice say after choice 1 ran, for an option to open a text file how would i go about that? As I can get the option for it but the text file wont open

Comment: you'd need to have a separate function, with it's own choices and logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can just wrap the whole thing in another `while` loop:

```
while True:
    ...
    if k.lower() == "close":
        break
```

You can use this same form to make your existing loop neater, removing the `errorch` flag:

```
while True:
    try:
        choice = int(input('Please Choose from Options below :'))
    except ValueError as e :
        print ("'%s' is not a valid integer." % e.args[0].split(": ")[1])
    else:
        break
```